# Java as Windows Service - User data path

Tags: java, windows, apache, service, procrun

I am using Apache Procrun for installing a java programm as a service on windows 10. Installing the service is no problem and it mainly works as expected, however, the user data is not stored in the according user data directory under %appdata%. Win10 seems to redirect it to a virtual directory, but I am unable to locate it. It musst be somewhere in the windows directory unter System32 or SysWOW64. Can you give me a hint, where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\